# how to resize iframe height on browser resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to resize the iframe on window resize as well as the content within the iframe

Current the script I have seta the height on load only.

Can any one help??

Eaxmple attached

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/GRRWj/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){

        var iFrames = $('iframe');

        $(window).resize(iResize); //Execute function on every resize.

        function iResize() {

            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
              iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
            }

            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {

               iFrames.load(function(){
                   setTimeout(iResize, 0);
               });

               for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
               }

            } else {
               iFrames.load(function() {
                   this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
               });
            }

        });
```

Comment: Hi Chip - I've tryed this out - but its not working - I want the iframe height to resize as I make the browser smaller